# Is there a way to eject an iPhone directly from Xcode or from Mac OS X without using iTunes?

Tags: macos, iphone, xcode, eject

I’m using Xcode to develop an iOS app. So I connect my iPhone, and when I’m done developing I want to eject the phone to properly disconnect it. I have tried browsing around in the settings app and in Xcode and on Google, but I can’t find anything.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from this question and answer thread on the Apple-specific Stack Exchange site: 
[How do I safely eject or unplug an iPad, iPhone, or iPod when iTunes is not running?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/40630/40457)

> In the Finder in Mac OS X, press
>   <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to Go to folder. Type
>   `/Volumes`. This will take you to the “Volumes” folder. If your
>   iDevice is mounted as a drive, it will appear here. You can select it
>   and press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to eject it. If it does not
>   appear here, it is not mounted as a drive, and you can simply unplug
>   it. Note that it may or may not appear on your Desktop or in a Finder
>   sidebar depending on your settings, but it should always appear in the
>   `/Volumes` folder.

Comment: What I have been doing so far is stop running the app and then just plug the phone out. Does this affect the phone?